# How to find out which windows version my product key matches?

Tags: windows-8, installation, product-key

I retrieved my Windows 8 product key from the firmware but have no idea which version it's supposed to match. My Windows 8 cannot be booted into (hence the need to re-install in the first place)

How do I find out the correct version of Windows that my product key matches with?

Comment: What version came with the PC? There should also be a sticker which indicates which version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows includes a DLL called `pidgenx.dll` which includes this function:

```
[DllImport("pidgenx.dll", EntryPoint = "PidGenX", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int PidGenX(string productKey, string pkeyPath, string mspid, int unknownUsage, IntPtr productID, IntPtr digitalProductID, IntPtr digitalProductID4);
```

For pkeyPath Windows setup passes a path to [pkeyconfig.xrm-ms. In this file, the product key are defined and in the digitalProductID4 (last parameter), the Edition and Product key type (MSDN, Retail, Trial) is encoded](https://github.com/chughes-3/UpdateProductKey/blob/master/UpdateProductKeys/PidChecker.cs).

The [Ultimate PID Checker](http://web.archive.org/web/20160102003915/http://en.janek2012.eu/ultimate-pid-checker/) is one of several tools that call the function to decode the key.

[image]

Here you can see which edition the key belongs to.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @Jerther I've added a link to the web archive with a cached version of the website