# Find out which version/edition of windows a serial key can unlock?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-activation

A long time ago I bought a windows 8/8.1 key but I haven't used it.
I want to install it on a new machine but I can't remember if it's windows 8 or 8.1, nor which edition it is. Is there any way to check this?

An [identical question](https://superuser.com/questions/987859/how-to-find-out-which-windows-version-my-product-key-matches) has been asked before, but the solution there doesn't work for my key - possibly it's because that program doesn't support windows 8.1 keys.

Is there a more current solution for this problem?

Comment: Email to MS support.

Comment: I second that. There is no way to figure out other then trying to activate it.